# if a page has been idle for a while, it redirects the user to the main page insted of doing the requested action?

Tags: php, redirect

I'm looking over a website that has an unusual behavior.
I can't reproduce it on demand, but if the current page has been idle for a while (not sure for how long, but seems like it varies), it doesn't execute the requested command. Instead, it redirects to the main page - which is the homepage for the backend/admin panel on this particular site.
It doesn't log the user out or anything. Just redirects to the homepage.

This is very frustrating since sometimes my client fills out a lot of data into forms, and when he then clicks "submit", all data is lost.

Any ideas to what can cause something like that?
There's no CMS in use. This backend has been built from the ground up by another programmer some time ago..

Any suggestion is very appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a failing routine. It should destroy the session due to inactivity and redirect the user to do a new login, but something broke it (or it never worked properly)

Comment: if sessions (and/or cookies, tokens etc.) are involved, could be a timeout somewhere

Comment: Since the user isn't logged out, just redirected, you might be on to something. But how would I test something like that? I know there is a timeout on the session. php.ini has this line: session.gc_maxlifetime = 28800;

Comment: many ways. One of which would be to check if (and only if sessions/cookies are involved) they are set/not empty, then perform the action. JS/Ajax could be used for this along with a setInterval to refresh an iframe, if you want to go that route. `else{ // do something }`